# Implement Splitapp in Webide

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I'm new to the world of SAPUI5. I'm trying to simulate the master-detail template using SplitApp in webide. But I'm even unable to achieve the first step - I'm unable to make the SplitApp container work. I mean the container shows a page like below -

[SplitApp root view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kg9v2.png)

But it's not using my Master and detail pages, I believe this is just the default structure of SplitApp.
For testing I put some content in the master and detail pages, but they are not appearing.

This is the file structure:

[File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSZW2.png)

I'm attaching the manifest.json code

```js
{
 "_version": "1.3.0",
 "sap.app": {
  "_version": "1.3.0",
  "id": "com.md1",
  "type": "application",
  "i18n": "i18n/i18n.properties",
  "title": "{{appTitle}}",
  "description": "{{appDescription}}",
  "applicationVersion": {
   "version": "1.0.0"
  },
  "dataSources": {
   "ES4": {
    "uri": "/destinations/ES4/sap/opu/odata/IWBEP/GWSAMPLE_BASIC/",
    "type": "OData",
    "settings": {
     "odataVersion": "2.0"
    }
   },
   "GWSAMPLE_BASIC": {
    "uri": "/destinations/ES4/sap/opu/odata/IWBEP/GWSAMPLE_BASIC/",
    "type": "OData",
    "settings": {
     "odataVersion": "2.0",
     "localUri": "webapp/localService/metadata.xml"
    }
   }
  },
  "sourceTemplate": {
   "id": "servicecatalog.connectivityComponent",
   "version": "0.0.0"
  }
 },
 "sap.ui": {
  "_version": "1.3.0",
  "technology": "UI5",
  "icons": {
   "icon": "sap-icon://detail-view",
   "favIcon": "",
   "phone": "",
   "phone@2": "",
   "tablet": "",
   "tablet@2": ""
  },
  "deviceTypes": {
   "desktop": true,
   "tablet": true,
   "phone": true
  },
  "supportedThemes": [
   "sap_hcb",
   "sap_bluecrystal"
  ]
 },
 "sap.ui5": {
  "_version": "1.2.0",
  "rootView": {
   "viewName": "com.md1.view.App",
   "type": "XML",
   "id": "app"
  },
  "dependencies": {
   "minUI5Version": "1.36.0",
   "libs": {
    "sap.ui.core": {
     "minVersion": "1.36.0"
    },
    "sap.m": {
     "minVersion": "1.36.0"
    }
   }
  },
  "contentDensities": {
   "compact": true,
   "cozy": true
  },
  "models": {
   "i18n": {
    "type": "sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel",
    "settings": {
     "bundleName": "com.md1.i18n.i18n"
    }
   },
   "": {
    "dataSource": "ES4"
   }
  },
  "routing": {
   "config": {
    "routerClass": "sap.m.routing.Router",
    "viewType": "XML",
    "viewPath": "com.md1.view",
    "controlId": "idAppControl",
    "controlAggregation": "detailPages",
    "bypassed": {
     "target": [
      "master",
      "notFound"
     ]
    },
    "async": true
   },
   "routes": [
    {
     "pattern": "",
     "name": "master",
     "target": [
      "object",
      "master"
     ]
    },
    {
     "pattern": "SalesOrderSet/{objectId}",
     "name": "object",
     "target": [
      "master",
      "object"
     ]
    }
   ],
   "targets": {
    "master": {
     "viewName": "Master",
     "viewLevel": 1,
     "viewId": "master",
     "controlAggregation": "masterPages"
    },
    "object": {
     "viewName": "Detail",
     "viewId": "detail",
     "viewLevel": 2
    },
    "detailObjectNotFound": {
     "viewName": "DetailObjectNotFound",
     "viewId": "detailObjectNotFound"
    },
    "detailNoObjectsAvailable": {
     "viewName": "DetailNoObjectsAvailable",
     "viewId": "detailNoObjectsAvailable"
    },
    "notFound": {
     "viewName": "NotFound",
     "viewId": "notFound"
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

.

I know it's too much to ask, but I'll be really grateful if you help me resolve this. I have found many examples of using SplitApp in google, but they all are using Javascript view in Eclipse. I need to do it in webide with XML view.

Thanks,
Sarif

Comment: Have you initialized your router in your `Component.js init()` function? You can do this by calling `this.getRouter().initialize();`

Comment: Actually I didn't and doing so solved my issue......thanks a lot